# Firebase rules read/write and security

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Probably a simple question.

I have a page with a single button and when people click, it should increment by 1.

But i had to set the following Rules so everyone could write to the database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

Will this have any security implications? or is this perfectly safe?

Comment: If I were to access your database and change that value from1 to 1 million, would that affect your app?

Comment: You can write ".read": true ;). My advice is to close absolutely all data and give minimal data access for your users.

Comment: @Jay Yes in that the number wouldn't be accurate then! There is no way to restrict the source of the data to script only? (i assume not since all client side can be tampered with)

Comment: You need to set up rules to only allow authenticated users to access that node and also limit increments to 1 etc.